# Mysql high cpu usage (over 600%)

Tags: mysql, server, phpmyadmin, innodb

here is my mysql configuration file:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
##
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
key_buffer_size     = 1G
max_allowed_packet  = 256M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 300


#innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
#innodb_read_io_threads=8
#innodb_write_io_threads=8

#open_files_limit = 1024
#table_open_cache = 400
server_id           = 2
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
log_bin             = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log.index
relay_log           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
relay_log_index     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size     = 100M
log_slave_updates   = 1
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 2
replicate-ignore-db=phpmyadmin
replicate-ignore-db=mysql
skip-name-resolve
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 0
query_cache_size        = 0

sort_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M



#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

The server has 8core CPU and 22 GB of ram. Every day receives many requests from users, and recently a replication mechanism has been activated, with an implementation of a db master and a slave.
Now the server is really slow (on ssh top, mysqld reaches 600% and more of CPU Usage) and sometimes it go down of service. Please can you help me to fix this issue?

Comment: "Please can you help me to fix this issue?" No not without a `EXPLAIN <query>` which query or queries are the cause of the 600% CPU time

Comment: Hi. Most likely one or more queries are causing the problem so you need to do more troubleshooting on your server to figure this out. The only thing anyone here could help you with would be to reduce the maximum cpu usage, by tuning the configuration, but that would just make those queries take longer to execute, you wouldn't be solving the underlying problem.

Comment: @RaymondNijland It is not a particular query, as I wrote, there are hundreds of users who use the software every day, and hundreds of queries are made for each user who uses it. What I found looking on the net, is that it could be a bad mysql configuration.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen before updating, I used ubuntu 14 and mysql 5.5, and there were none of these problems, moreover the queries are simple. For this I would exclude that the problem is caused by queries.

Comment: When you have 8 cores, 600% is acceptable as long as you do NOT STAY stuck at 600% when viewing TOP or HTOP type of data, since each core could be busy 100% for their part of the processing.

Comment: High CPU is almost always caused by a single slow query.  Show us that query, its `EXPLAIN`, and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The solution may be as simple as devising a 'composite' `INDEX`, or reformulating the query.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog for tips on finding the slow query.

Comment: @Antony,  Need fresh SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; when time permits.  Please post to pastebin.com and share the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second=RPS
Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 8 for multi-threading w 8 cores CAP at 100 per V 5.7
```

## the following 4 are per CONNECTION RAM requests

```
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from 1M to reduce sort_merge_passes
read_buffer_size=128K  # from 1M to reduce handler_read_next RPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from ? may reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
join_buffer_size=128K  # from 1M for join row pointers
```

please view my profile, Network profile for contact info including my Skype ID and get in touch when you have 5 minutes.  Still need SHOW GLOBAL STATUS and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second=RPS  Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=1500  # from 200 to enable higher RD & WD IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 for minimum to reduce CPU busy every SECOND
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=15  # from 25 percent since less than 1% used Del,Ins,Upd
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty
innodb_thread_concurrency=12  # from 6 to utilize more of your 8 core capacity
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct=90  # from 25 percent to warm more of BP on start of instance
```

Looking forward to Skype session with you in a few hours.  Thanks, Wilson